# BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to insert an array of objects (data pulled from an external api)into a mongoDB using db.collection.insert . After few documents are inserted, I am getting this error:

BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: bitcoin.bitcoins index: *id* dup key: { : ObjectId('5c7ee21ef0d6e663e84ef577')

I tried dropping the database too but of no use. Also ids are autogenerated by Mongo.

Code looks like :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const rp = require('request-promise');
const moment = require('moment');

var Bitcoin = require('../models/bitcoin_model');
var bitcoinArray = [];

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries',
  json: true
};

setInterval(function () {
  rp(options)
    .then(function (response) {
      response.result.forEach((item) => {
        bitcoinArray.push({
          timestamp: item.TimeStamp,
          marketname: item.MarketName,
          high: item.High,
          low: item.Low,
          volume: item.BaseVolume
        })
      })

      bitcoinArray.forEach((item) => console.log(item));
      Bitcoin.collection.insertMany(bitcoinArray, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          console.log("Multiple documents inserted to Collection");
        }
      });

    })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}, 60000);
```

Model looks like :

```js
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var bitcoinSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      timestamp: Date,
      marketname: String,
      high: Number,
      low: Number,
      volume: Number
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('bitcoin', bitcoinSchema);
```

Comment: It looks like your using Mongoose as an ODM? Can you post the relevant code for the Bitcoin model?

Comment: Thanks !! Yes .. I use Mongoose together with nodejs to connect to mongodb..have added the schema details above ..

Comment: It doesn't look like it, but just to make sure, are you indexing any fields in your Bitcoin collection with a `unique: true` option?

Comment: Do you know where the id field is coming from? Mongo uses `_id` for its internals, so I'm curious where `id` is being created.

Comment: No..I have not indexed any of the fields using the unique option.. I am not adding _id from my code. Mongo is auto-generating it. I do not know how it is then generating duplicate ids.